# Hide CheckBox IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to remove a checkbox client-side. Works fine in Chrome. Can't get it to go in IE8.

```
document.getElementById('CheckBox3').style.display = 'none';
```

I've also tried `style.visibility = 'hidden'`, `style.visibility = 'collapse'`, as well as disabling the CheckBox. I am able to remove a label to the left of it no problem -- all these means work, but none work for removing the CheckBox.

Any ideas?

```
<td class="DatapointsCheckbox">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
</td>
```

There's the mark-up.

```
.DatapointsCheckbox
{
    width: 40px;
}
```

That's the CSS...

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYQJN.png
HTML Mark-Up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cinf.png (SS of relevant markup, at least)

Comment: I see you are using ASP.NET. Is the ID the same after its output?

Comment: Are you sure the style on the element isn't being overridden by a CSS style mark !important?

Comment: Can you show us the inherited style on the input element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it should be:

```
document.getElementById('<%= CheckBox3.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

In ASP.Net the client ID of the control is compiled at run time and will look like `parent1_parent2_parent3_theControl`. Using "ClientID" will give you the full ID of the control. If you don't use that I wouldn't expect it to work in any browser, ever.

Comment: Hi, I went ahead and made your suggested change, but I saw no difference in any browser. Perhaps I was just getting lucky that it worked before, though.

Comment: Perhaps you have JS errors on the page so your JS code isn't getting reached? Hit F12 in IE8 to open the Developer Tools - there you can inspect the elements and even set breakpoints on your JS code and debug it.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I checked for it and did not see any errors. In addition, other controls located adjacent to CheckBox3 are being removed without fuss.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML output so I can look at it? (Or give a link to a public URL.)

Comment: I've edited in a copy/paste of the saved HTML. I apologize in advance for any ugly programming -- web development is not something I've mastered (clearly..) -- One moment... copy/pasting the entire mark-up isn't really workable as it's just a pop-up window, attempting to isolate the relevant code.